# Get the product ID in woocommerce_product_get_image filter hook

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

Some of our products are using an external image instead of the post thumbnail, I have an acf set up for this url. It appears that you can filter the woocommerce `get_image()` function, but I can't find a way to get the current product's id to get the field.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function offsite_product_images($image_url, //variable $this wont work here){
    //need some way to get the current product's id
    if(get_field('thumbnail_url', $id)){
        $image_url = get_field('thumbnail_url', $id);
    }
    return $image_url;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_image', 'offsite_product_images');
```

the woocommerce get_image() function:

```
public function get_image( $size = 'woocommerce_thumbnail', $attr = array(), $placeholder = true ) {
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $this->get_id() ) ) {
        $image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $this->get_id(), $size, $attr );
    } elseif ( ( $parent_id = wp_get_post_parent_id( $this->get_id() ) ) && has_post_thumbnail( $parent_id ) ) {
        $image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $parent_id, $size, $attr );
    } elseif ( $placeholder ) {
        $image = wc_placeholder_img( $size );
    } else {
        $image = '';
    }

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_get_image', wc_get_relative_url( $image ), $this, $size, $attr, $placeholder, $image );
}
```

I even tried changing the function to pass the id directly, but it wouldn't do it.

Any help on getting the product or it's id passed to my filter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function code is incomplete, there is some missing arguments as the `WC_Product` object, that you need to get the product ID. Try the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_image', 'offsite_product_images', 10, 5 );
function offsite_product_images( $image, $product, $size, $attr, $placeholder ){
    if( get_field('thumbnail_url', $product->get_id() ) ){
        $image = get_field('thumbnail_url', $product->get_id() );
    }
    return $image;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: i put those arguments in before but i kept getting these errors: `Warning: Missing argument 2 for offsite_product_images()` but your code did the trick